# Unable to get the concept of popping navigation control in current class

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

```
self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

So in above line i am having confusion that why I am getting navigation controller instance in the current class. According to the storyboard, navigation controller is present outside this class, but how come are we accessing the navigation controller in the current class?

Comment: What is self? A UIViewController? It's because that's how it's built. A NavigationController will be a top level and will present a UIViewController. If you don't use a UINavigationController, self.navigationController would be nil.

Comment: refer this URL i guess you will make clear with your confusion : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current `viewController` is being managed by the `navigationController`.

You could think of it in a similar way to a parent / child relationship. The `navigationController` is somewhat functioning like the parent of the `viewController`.

That property provides a reference to the `navigationController` provided it exists. In the same way you can say `view.superView` to access the parent view that the current view is inside.

Comment: Thanks. Understood the concept! :)